# $p_{n+1} \le p_1p_2...p_{n} + 1$ proof?

Tags: number-theory

The book I'm reading states $p_{n+1} \le p_1p_2...p_{n} + 1$ without any proof and I can't seem to understand why this is, could someone explain why this is true? $(p_k$ is consecutive primes$)$.

I see that no $p_k$ for $1\lt k \lt n$ divides $p_1 \dots p_n$, but from here I can't see how the next prime is less than this product and sum.

Comment: see the p1p2...pn - 1

Comment: Well, $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n + 1$ must have some prime divisors right? Can those divisors be less than $p_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: Do you mean "_all_ $p_k$ for $1\leq k \leq n$ divides $p_1\cdots p_n$"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number $t=p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ has no prime divisor among $p_1, \ldots p_n$.  Hence it must have some prime divisor $p_{n+j}$.  Hence  $p_{n+1}\le p_{n+j}\le t$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume there are no primes between $p_n$ and $p_1\ldots p_n+1$, then it is easy to see that $p_1\ldots p_k+1$ must be prime, so $p_{n+1} = p_1\ldots p_k+1$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: $p_1*p_2+1 = p_4$ fail.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a prime factor of $p_1\cdots p_n+1$.

Because all $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ divide $p_1\cdots p_n$, you have that none of these divide $p_1\cdots p_n+1$.

So $p\notin\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$.